# Adjust pane size in vim

Tags: linux, vim

I know I can use `:sp` or `:vsp` to open files in vim in splitted panes. But how can I increase/decrease the size of each pane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `:[vertical] resize [+]N`, or alternatively the `[N]<C-W>_` / `[N]<C-W>-` / `[N]<C-W>-` (for vertical: `|` / `<` / `>`) normal mode commands. (`[N]` is the size (difference) in display cells.)

If the mouse is enabled, you can also resize by dragging the separator line.

Comment: This commands do not work. I tried `:[vertical] resize +20` and `:[sp] resize +20` and `:vertical resize 20` but I get `Not an editor command`

Comment: Also I did `:set mouse=a` but could not move the pane using the mouse

Comment: What's your Vim version? `:version`??

Comment: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Dec 27 2011 23:37:12)`

Comment: What about plain `:resize 20`? And the normal mode commands? Unless you have a _tiny_ build, these all should work.

Comment: This seems to work but not for `vim -O file1 file2`. Also how do I enable mouse that you mention?

Comment: With vertical splits (`-O`), that would be `:vertical resize 20`, as I've written. Mouse with `:set mouse=a`, but it depends on the terminal.

Comment: +1. Actually I tried `:set mouse=a` but it did not work

Comment: I'll open a separate question for that

Answer (score -1):

Try `Ctrl-W +` and `Ctrl-W -` for one-above-the-other split panes.  For side-by-side split panes, use Ctrl-W followed by right or left arrow keys.  (Prefix a count to do it in one step.)